# Rpi3B+ and Audio Amplifier HAT GPIO Pin Push Button False Detection/Triggering Problem

Tags: gpio, python, pi-3b+

I'm currently having trouble with my project. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with an [InnoMaker Hifi Amp Hat](http://www.inno-maker.com/product/hifi-amp-hat/) and some push buttons.

```py
import time
import signal
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

debounceTime = 300

btn1 = 24
btn2 = 25
btn3 = 13
btn4 = 12
btn5 = 16

def cb_btn1(channel):
    print('Button 1 pressed')

def cb_btn2(channel):
    print('Button 2 pressed')

def cb_btn3(channel):
    print('Button 3 pressed')

def cb_btn4(channel):
    print('Button 4 pressed')

def cb_btn5(channel):
    print('Button 5 pressed')

class GracefulExit:
    kill_now = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self,signum, frame):
        self.kill_now = True

GPIO.setup(btn1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(btn2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(btn3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(btn4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(btn5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

GPIO.add_event_detect(btn1, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_btn1, bouncetime=debounceTime)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn2, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_btn2, bouncetime=debounceTime)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn3, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_btn3, bouncetime=debounceTime)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn4, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_btn4, bouncetime=debounceTime)
GPIO.add_event_detect(btn5, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_btn5, bouncetime=debounceTime)

def main():
    app_killer = GracefulExit()
    while not app_killer.kill_now:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except BaseException:
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print "Encountered an axeption."
            break
    print "End of the program."
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried with external pull-up/down and also adding a 0.1uF cap between 3.3V / GND and the GPIO.

I'm not using any pins that the Hat is supposed to use (GPIOs 18 to 21) according to [the manual](https://www.jianguoyun.com/p/DcAI8PcQpdSrBxjBrZ0B#file=%2FUser%20Manual%2FHIFI%20AMP%20HAT%20User%20Manual%20V1.2.pdf::size=4382400)

My setup us currently on a breadboard, maybe I'm getting EMI with the jumpers wires...

I'm using a good quality power supply so I hope the problem isn't coming from here...
For reference it's a [Mean Well GSM40A12-P1J](https://es.rs-online.com/web/p/fuentes-de-alimentacion-de-sobremesa/7911027/?relevancy-data=636F3D3126696E3D4931384E53656172636847656E65726963266C753D6573266D6D3D6D61746368616C6C7061727469616C26706D3D5E5B5C707B4C7D5C707B4E647D2D2C2F255C2E5D2B2426706F3D31333326736E3D592673723D4175746F636F727265637465642673613D67736D34306131322673743D4B4559574F52445F53494E474C455F414C5048415F4E554D455249432673633D592677633D4E4F4E45267573743D47533430413132267374613D4753343041313226&searchHistory=%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D)

I've discovered that touching the metal Ethernet/USB port with the metal tip of an USB flash drive or the tips of my multimeter probe trigger almost all my GPIO each times.

Is there something that I'm missing to get reliable input?

[image: Schematics]
[image: Pi header]
[image: Breadboard pictures]

---

Edit:
Ok I'm slowly putting the pieces together. In order to make `pigpiod` running on a non full raspbian image in addition to `sudo apt install pigpiod`I had to run `sudo apt install python3-pigpio`

Comment: I wouldn't expect that problem with the set up as described.  Could we have a clear photo showing the connections to the Pi?

Comment: I've removed the GPIO protection resistors since they aren't mandatory and make the setup clearer on the pictures

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with `pigpiod`, I've installed it via `sudo apt install pigpiod`and running via `sudo pigpiod`. Trying to run the script tells me `ImportError: No module named pigpio`. Is there any additional package to install? I can't see on PyPl any python module called `pigpio` only `apigpio` but I'm assuming that this is totally different?

Comment: I'm running Raspbian Lite, if I `ps -aux`I can see `root      2400  6.3  0.1   9976  1632 ?        SLsl 04:07   0:12 pigpiod` but then when I try `python monitor.py`I have `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "monitor.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pigpio
ImportError: No module named pigpio`

If I try `sudo pigpiod`again I have `2019-10-17 05:49:58 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid
Can't initialise pigpio library`

Comment: You can say which GPIO to monitor.  In this case the switches so run as `./monitor.py 12 13 16 24 25`

Comment: Ok I've updated the output on my post, should I run monitor.py while my other python script is running? I don't really understand the output. There is a lot of things going, I don't know if I was supposed to get outputs only when a button is being pressed ?

Comment: Ok the output I was getting was because I run monitor.py without my script in the background. Now I'm waiting for a false trigger. I've also added more ground pin on my breadboard

Comment: I've updated the output with my script running in background and monitor.py is showing me that GPIO18 is set to high quite often...

Comment: Yes of course sorry I mistyped 18 instead of 16 on the command line

Comment: I'm letting my script running to see if I still have more ghost triggering but meanwhile I'm testing something else: When I tickle the USB port of mi Pi with a piece of wire (not shorting anything just touching the USB / Ethernet housing) and the other end of the wire in my hand, I manage to trigger my event on my script, but monitor.py doesn't show anything... Any thought?

Comment: monitor.py uses pigpio callbacks which use (by default) 5µs sampling.  If the triggering event was shorter than 5µs it would not always be detected.  RPi.GPIO uses Linux interrupt edge triggering which means it will see an event even if it only lasts a few nanoseconds.  Th bouncetime setting doesn't help as that simply ignores any further events in the bouncetime period.

Comment: I've left my script running all day and I had 2 false trigger (each time I have a false trigger nearly all button events are triggered at the same time) but nothing was detected by monitor.py. I'm considering changing my python script to use pigpio since apparently it's more reliable. Is there a straight way and painless way to transition my script to pigpio?

Comment: Unless you are planning to do a lot more GPIO work I'd stick to RPi.GPIO.  It is better suited to your particular task.

Comment: @Sébastien, Ah, let me see.  Your GPIO button false triggering sounds interesting.  It appears that the problem is only related to the push button detection circuit, and has nothing to do with the HiFi amplifier HAT.  Anyway, now let me see if I can set up a very simple one push button circuit and reproduce you false triggering problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mitigate against unwanted events I suggest you use code similar to the following. Basically read the level of the GPIO in the callback to verify it is not a short term transient.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import signal
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

buttons=[24, 25, 13, 12, 16]

def cb_buttons(channel):
   if GPIO.input(channel) == 0:
      btn = buttons.index(channel) + 1
      print("Button {} pressed".format(btn))

class GracefulExit:
    kill_now = False
    def __init__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self,signum, frame):
        self.kill_now = True

for btn in buttons:
   GPIO.setup(btn, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
   GPIO.add_event_detect(btn, GPIO.FALLING, callback=cb_buttons)

def main():
    app_killer = GracefulExit()
    while not app_killer.kill_now:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except BaseException:
            GPIO.cleanup()
            print "Encountered an axeption."
            break
    print "End of the program."
    GPIO.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'm letting the script running, I can't manage to get the event to trigger accidentally now when I'm inserting an USB thumb drive, that's already a win there

Comment: It's being almost 24h and not a single false triggering with your improvement!